# BSNL EVDO Ubuntu 14.04 connected but no internet

Tags: 14.04

I have BSNL EVDO connected in Ubuntu, but still when I try to access page via browser it shows "Internet Unavailable". At other times, its not even getting connected, I have tried using `wvdial` and after showing four DNS servers it halts and doesn't show connected for long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gnome-ppp package by :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp
```

It's a graphical interface which does same work as `wvdial`.
Open it from the applications panel and in settings try "detect serial port". And manually change the modem type to "USB" and save. On main screen enter the credentials and try connecting. Let us know what you get.

Comment: I got it connected using gnome-ppp

Though it shows speed of 3100000, status: Idle and recieved and sent data is very less. how do I increase speed? I still cannot open any web page in browser